# How to make that WPF ComboBox keyboard text search will works correctly if IsEditable and IsReadOnly is true?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello every one I have a problem with WPF ComboBox look at the code

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True">
<ComboBoxItem>dsf gd</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem>asf gd</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem>dsf gd</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem>hsf gd</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

requirement is that the text in ComboBox can be selected, text search by key first letter shold work, and the comboBox should be editable 
I set the properties

```
IsReadOnly="True" 
IsEditable="True"
```

but Text search doesn't work.
Help me resolve this issue, please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly does not work, and what happens? When I tried your code it worked. I made IsEditable=true it works also (and is easier to see, since you see the text.

Comment: doesn't work the search via pressing key for example if you press key "a" in ComboBox should be selected item with text first letter "a". this behavior doesn't work if I set IsEditable = true;

Answer (score 20):

Try `IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="<PropertyName>"` where `<PropertyName>` is a property in the items of your `ItemsSource`.

Comment: When the IsEditable = true; the text search doesn't work. this is main problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you can resolve your problem by removing IsReadOnly property. You set it to *true*, so ComboBox doesn`t accept any input. If you don`t want an empty item as a first ComboBox item, you can set 
**SelectedIndex**="0".

Comment: thanks for answer but the requirement is the combobox should be readonly.

Comment: @Serghei, you said that ComboBox should be editable. How can it be editable and read-only at the same time? If you don\`t need to edit it\`s items, then you can set **IsEditable** to false and remove **IsReadOnly**.

Comment: The ComboBox should be editable only for text selection when the focus in ComboBox the text in it should be selected at the same time the ComboBox should be readonly

Comment: @Serghei From the problem statement "comboBox should be editable".  "Editable only for text selection" is not what IsEditable means.

Comment: @BalamBalam yes I know you a right, but how to implement text selection and not set IsEditale in true?

Comment: @Serghei, I don`t think you can make selectable text in ComboBox with just IsEditable and IsReadOnly. You\`ll have to play with ItemTemplate here.